# problem to write correct JSON for http connector in Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I need to retrieve data from an API. The JSON Payload must looks like this and this is working in Postman:

```
{
  "Ticket": "ticket",
  "TrimResponse": 0,
  "Data": {
    "EmployeeI3Ds": [
     22
    ],
   "StartDate": "\/Date(1710374400000)\/",
    "EndDate": "\/Date(1710460799000)\/"
  }
}
```

**"CreatedDateStart": "/Date(1709951998000+0200)/"** needs to be formated as shown.

When I use that in power automate http connector the following JSON is created while running the flow:

```
{
  "Ticket": "Ticket",
  "TrimResponse": 0,
  "Data": {
    "EmployeeI3Ds": [
      29
    ],
    "StartDate": "/Date(1710028800000)/",
    "EndDate": "/Date(1710115199000)/"
  }
}
```

The `\` at the beginning and at the end are removed by Power Automate

What I need to do, to get the exact notation in the http connector?

Robert

Syntax is working in Postman.
The REST-request is working without the date filters.
I already tried to escape that but was not successfull.

Comment: I have tried everything I can think of, even down to translating back from a base64 string, like this ... `base64ToString('XC8=')` ... and it still throws two slashes in instead of one.  I have another idea so leave it with me.

Comment: Thanks a million @Skin!  Same issue here.

I'll raise a case with Microsoft!

Comment: I even tried through C# code in the advanced data operations connector and it didn’t work either. Keen to know how you go with Microsoft. Might take some time though: